# Microsoft JScript runtime error Win CE hand held scanner

Tags: javascript, html, runtime, windows-ce, jscript

I have the below piece of code which runs great on all browsers down to IE5.

```
<form action="/scanners/picking_list.php" method="POST" name="the_form" onsubmit="return getInputsByValue();">
        <table id="the_table">
                <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="picking_list[]" value="910774" data-src="MAN-910774" checked></td>
        <td><span class="popup-handler" onclick="toggle_popup('DN.MAN-910774')">MAN-910774</span></td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Pick Despatches" name="submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

<p id="MAN-910774" style="display: none;">DN.MAN-910774 Picking Notes:\n\nTESTING COMMENT</p>

<script>
function getInputsByValue()
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName("picking_list[]");
        var index;
        for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; index++) {
            if (inputs[index].checked) {
                var dataSrc = document.getElementsByName("picking_list[]")[index].getAttribute("data-src");
                console.log(dataSrc);
                if (document.getElementById(dataSrc)) {
                    var commentSrc = document.getElementById(dataSrc).innerHTML;
                    console.log(commentSrc);
                    if (!confirm(commentSrc)) return false;
                }
            }
        }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

What it does is loop through the checkboxes and see if they're checked. If they are, it then adds the comment which is the hidden p tag and creates an alert popup.

When I run this on a hand-held scanner running Windows CE I get the following message:

Microsoft JScript runtime error

Line: 4 Character: 4
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
Source: (null)

Comment: `console.log()` works in IE5???

Comment: Well, It's IE11 in IE5 mode, but the script works. It works perfectly until I try it on the hand held device.

Comment: Just remove the loggings and try again. IE11 can't emulate IE5, results are more or less unreliable.

Comment: Done, but the error still happens?